# How to filter duplicates in MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some the columns A to D and would like to filter duplicates. We have a duplicate if column A and B have the same value. The returned value in columns C and D should be any value that is stated in one of the aggregated lines.

I tried to fix it with "Group By" but I don't know what to do with the columns C and D. I do not need a aggregated value and it is possible that there is test in the corresponding fields.

**EDIT**

Sample data:

Starting point:

```
A B C D
1 2 4 1
1 2 3 2
2 2 4 1
2 2 3 1
1 2 1 2
```

expected result:

```
A B C D
1 2 4 1
2 2 4 1
```

where the columns C and D could be any of the possible values.

I tried:

```
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D
From DB.T1
Grouped By A, B
```

but this does not work.

Comment: good luck. unless you show some sample data and your attempts, it would be hard for people to answer.

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You can try looking at `Common Table Expressions` ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx ) along with `OVER` and `ROW_NUMBER()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: why your result return `1 2 4 1` over  `1 2 3 2` or `1 2 1 2` ?? What is the logic, the largest?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - why ask that question he said it does not matter.

Comment: @Hogan Sorry for me wasnt clear.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the result does not matter to me! I dont care if it returns 1241, 1232 or 1212!

Comment: well then Hogan answer should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Little hard to tell from what you said but you probably want something like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
   SELECT T1.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY C, D) AS RN
   FROM T1

 ) X
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you for your problem :

Your solution :

`select A
      ,B
      ,C
      ,D
  from test_table
 group by A
         ,B`

You can try this for problem :

`select A
      ,B
      ,max(C)
      ,max(D)
  from test_table
--where C = 4 or C = 3 or D = ... etc
 group by A
         ,B`

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b8734/2/0)

Comment: Hey, tahnks for your answer. This would be possible if i would have int values in my fields. Sadly there are some text values as well. In Access I would use the "FIRST()" function, is there an equivalent in MS Server?

Comment: Yes, you can use this

Comment: Hey, i tried it but it does not work out. Here my syntax:

SELECT        

Max(Name)

, ID_group

, Max(Age)

, max(time)

, max(date)

FROM Table1

Grouped By ID_group

Comment: I suppose Name is string data type, may you try select name, id_group, max(age), max(time), max(date) from table1 group by name, id_group

Comment: okay, but I dont want to group name as well, this would not solve my problem!

Comment: Hey, i try your code its works, grouped by -> group by see there [link: sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/753d3/2/0)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort! In case I have a column filled with "BIT" the Max-Operator is invalid :-(!

Comment: What data type BIT column ?

Comment: Datatype is "bit" and this is a boolean, the value is True or False

Comment: Use this MAX(CASE WHEN BIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)